# Instantiating tag objects using jsoup

Tags: java, tags, jsoup

I am trying to create a new `Element` using jsoup.

Element constructor:

```
Element(Tag tag, String baseUri, Attributes attributes)
```

I have problems instantiating the `Tag` object, because the constructor is not visible.

How can I obtain a `Tag`, apart from getting an existing one from another element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the static generator method [`valueOf`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Tag.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Tag t = Tag.valueOf("p");
```

The reason that `Tag` doesn’t expose a constructor is that the `valueOf` method can cache identical objects. For instance, this allows the following code:

```
Tag u = Tag.valueOf("p");
assert t == u;
```